# Accessing weights of a bmesh

Tags: python, vertex-weights

I triangulated a mesh using `bmesh.ops.triangulate`, and I don't know how to access the weights of vertex groups. The traditional `MeshVertex` has a `groups` field that contains these weights. I tried to find it in the bmesh layers, but there are no layers in it.

Is there any way to access vertex weights from bmesh, or is it only available in `MeshVertex.groups`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's

```
layer_deform = bm.verts.layers.deform.active
assert layer_deform is not None

bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
bmv = bm.verts[0]
bmv[layer_deform][vertex_group_index] = weight

# or
names = tuple(vertex_group.name for vertex_group in obj.vertex_groups)

for vertex_group_index, weight in bmv[layer_deform].items():
    name = names[vertex_group_index]
    print("Name: %s, Weight: %f" % (name, weight))
```

Links:

- [bmesh.types.BMLayerAccessVert.deform](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMLayerAccessVert)
- [bmesh.types.BMDeformVert](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMDeformVert)