# How to get list of bm.verts that belong to a deform layer?

Tags: python, bmesh

I have a previously assigned Vertex Groups on my object. After creating the bmesh, if I understand correctly that Vertex Group should now be `dvert_lay = bm.verts.layers.deform.active`. If I print that, it looks like this:

```
<BMLayerItem object at 0x000002A7E18B5A50>
```

I'd like to get a list of bm.verts from my deform layer that could be used with bmesh.ops. It should have this format:

```
[<BMVert(0x000002A7818090B0), index=12>, <BMVert(0x000002A7818090E8), index=13>, <BMVert(0x000002A781809120), index=14>]
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I managed to find the values I needed by printing these variables:

```
# Layer Deform is the vertex group layer in bmesh mode.
layer_deform = bm.verts.layers.deform.active
if layer_deform is not None:
print('--- This is the deform layer info: ---')
    for vert in bm.verts:
        dvert = vert[layer_deform]
        print('vert index: ', vert.index, 'vert id:', vert,'vertex groups:', dvert.items()) #dvert.items gives you two elements: int of vertex group (I think by the order they were created added), and a 0.0 to 1.0 about the weight. If the vert doesn't belong to any vertex group, this dict will be emtpy. vert gives the BMVert in this format: BMVert(0x0000000012998B88)
print('--- End of deform layer info ---')
```

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69426/accessing-weights-of-a-bmesh