# foreach_get/set a mesh vertex group data?

Tags: python, mesh, vertex-groups

I'm searching how to batch set/get vertex group data inside blender.
using foreach_get() foreach_set() function from bpy.data.objects[0].data.vertices & numpy for a **fast** calculation.

but it seem that those two function only accept really simple properties? and batch actions on vertex_groups/vcol are not possible in blender ?

this code below is throwing me errors

`vertices[...]' elements have no attribute 'groups[0].weight'`

but this error message is False the elements does have this attribute !!

[image]

note that this error message also occur with getattr() and setattr()

```py
import bpy
import numpy as np

def print_weight(o, vg_name, use_modifiers=True):
    
    #eval object modifiers to mesh?
    if use_modifiers:
          depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
          eo = o.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
          ob = eo.to_mesh(preserve_all_data_layers=True, depsgraph=depsgraph)
    else: ob = o.data
        
    """ 
    #slow method
    weight_values = []
    for v in ob.vertices:
        weight_values.append( v.groups[o.vertex_groups[vg_name].index].weight )
    """
    #trying fast batch_get method, unsuccessful..
    weight_values = np.zeros((len(ob.vertices) * 3), dtype=np.float, )
    i = o.vertex_groups[vg_name].index
    ob.vertices.foreach_get(f"groups[{i}].weight", weight_values, )

    print(weight_values)
    return

    
    
print_weight(bpy.context.object,"Group")
```

Comment: Incorrect assumption. `groups[0].weight`  Is not one attribute.  `weight` is an attribute of `groups[0]`.

Comment: oh, of course ! then i assume there's no way to quickly batch get those properties, sad
Thanks for the answer

Comment: Don't think so since it will also be a task to size the flat array to populate.  Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135152/how-to-create-a-list-containing-lists-of-bm-verts-based-on-their-deform-layer-v

Comment: May also be of interest https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75223/finding-vertices-in-a-vertex-group-using-blenders-python-api

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely sure if this already is possible in some way but I made a patch last year that hasn't been reviewed yet to read/write vertex weights in batches. It speeds it up by around a factor of 8x. If you really really need it (and only on your computer) you can download and compile yourself.
https://developer.blender.org/D6227

Comment: Oh man, i really hope this will merged one day, I have addons that could heavily benefit from this patch.

Comment: I really need this patch lol. I see that the ```foreach_set/get``` patches got approved fast, could this be rewritten the same way to get it approved faster?

Comment: I'll see what I can do to speed it up. Would like to get it reviewed atleast so that I will know what to change / how to design it and hopefully have something ready for 2.92 if it's accepted.

Comment: Sorry for noobish question, but the patch will help "only" for custom addons & scripts, but it won't increase the speed of general Weight Painting (which is super-slow in case of larger meshes), right?